# I have some problems with creating a Click Event in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, events, textbox, click

I have a problem in Visual Studio 2008 C++ for creating a Click event on the TextBox. I have an array of TextBoxs and I need to add to them on a Click event. I try in this way:

Function of Click:

```
private: System::Void ButtonClickHandler(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) 
{
    //something   

}
```

Code for creating the click event:

```
this->text_edit[i]->Click +=gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &New::ButtonClickHandler);
```

The code is in this for:

```
for(i=0; i < howMany; i++)
{
    this->text_edit[i]=(gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());  
    this->text_edit[i]->AutoSize = true;  
    this->text_edit[i]->Location = System::Drawing::Point(where_X_Edit, where_Y_Edit);  
    this->text_edit[i]->Name = interf[i];  
    this->text_edit[i]->Size = System::Drawing::Size(90, 30);  
    this->text_edit[i]->TabIndex = 0;  
    this->text_edit[i]->Text = interf[i];
    this->text_edit[i]->Enabled=false;

    this->text_edit[i]->Click +=gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &New::ButtonClickHandler);

    panel->Controls->Add(this->text_edit[i]);
    where_Y_Edit += 32; 
}
```

The problem is with creating the click event, 9 errors only at that line of code.

```
Error   2   error C2653: 'New' : is not a class or namespace name   c:\users\uidw7119\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\datalogger\datalogger\DataView_Form.h   502
Error   3   error C2276: '&' : illegal operation on bound member function expression    c:\users\uidw7119\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\datalogger\datalogger\DataView_Form.h   502
Error   4   error C3350: 'System::EventHandler' : a delegate constructor expects 2 argument(s)  c:\users\uidw7119\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\datalogger\datalogger\DataView_Form.h   502
Error   13  error C2653: 'New' : is not a class or namespace name   c:\users\uidw7119\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\datalogger\datalogger\DataView_Form.h   502
Error   14  error C2276: '&' : illegal operation on bound member function expression    c:\users\uidw7119\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\datalogger\datalogger\DataView_Form.h   502
Error   15  error C3350: 'System::EventHandler' : a delegate constructor expects 2 argument(s)  c:\users\uidw7119\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\datalogger\datalogger\DataView_Form.h   502
Error   17  error C2653: 'New' : is not a class or namespace name   c:\users\uidw7119\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\datalogger\datalogger\DataView_Form.h   502
Error   18  error C2276: '&' : illegal operation on bound member function expression    c:\users\uidw7119\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\datalogger\datalogger\DataView_Form.h   502
Error   19  error C3350: 'System::EventHandler' : a delegate constructor expects 2 argument(s)  c:\users\uidw7119\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\datalogger\datalogger\DataView_Form.h   502
```

The secound question is more important than the first one:
If someone know it is possible to create a Click event on the TextBox that will have a function with others parameters that the `System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e`, something like this: `void ClickBtn(int value, String ^ something)`.

Comment: It says that `New` doesn't exist. Does `New` exist?

Comment: Do You have `New` defined somewhere? Maybe You're not including necessary header?

Comment: I use the same code that is used in generated code when you create a textbox, I don't know what new is, but in generated code is not defined.

Comment: Maybe You should look for `New::ButtonClickHandler` in Your code and see if it is defined. If it is, You should know which file to include in Your *.h file corresponding to window You're working on.

Comment: Don't work with New::ButtonClickHandler.

Comment: @AnDr3yy Did You find any `New` in Your project? Where do You have Your first function declared (this one: `private: System::Void ButtonClickHandler(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)` ). You should use class name inside which this function is defined.

Answer (score 0):

I manage to resolve the problem.

The correct code for creating the Click event is:

`this->text_edit[i]->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &DataView_Form::TextBoxClick);`

And `TextBoxClick` is the function `ButtonClickHandler` from the question.

`DataView_Form` is my form:

`public ref class DataView_Form : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{
   //code here
};`